# Repeating input to dictionary loop

Tags: python, dictionary

"Create a dictionary whose keys are names and whose value for a key is a favorite food of the person with that name as follows:
-   The program should prompt for a name and  favorite food and keep inputting names and favorite foods until the user enters an empty string for the name."

So far I have:

```
mydict=dict()
def favorite_food_name():
    name=input(str("name:"))
    food=input(str("food:"))
    mydict[name]=food       
    print(mydict)
favorite_food_name()
```

But I can't get the code to repeat in any kind of loop.  What kind of loop would you use?

Comment: I would definitely use a while loop.

Comment: use a while loop in function definition and return if name is an empty string (before proceeding to get food input)

Comment: What do you mean "I can't get the code to repeat in any kind of loop" ?? that is because in the code you posted you don't use any kind of loop...

Comment: You don't need to use `str()` around `"name:"`, since it's already a string.

Answer (score 0):

Use `While True` loop, and test value of `name` after its input.

By the way, some tips when coding:

- you do not need `str("name:")`, since `"name:"` is `str`
- if not necessary, put `mydict` in the function part, use `return` statement, do not use it as model level
- you can do more to validate the input, here I call a `strip` function to remove typo of input.

Here is a sample code:

```
def favorite_food_name():
    mydict = dict()
    while True:
        name = input("name:")
        name = name.strip()
        if name == '':
            break
        food = input("food:")
        food = food.strip()
        mydict[name] = food
    # print(mydict)
    return mydict


if __name__ == '__main__':
    mydict = favorite_food_name()
    print(mydict)
```

Comment: Thanks! This is close to what I need.  It's good to have it up.